# git production , development environment

Tags: python, git, version

I have a project of python files on a network drive called "Development".

I create branches off Development for new features and then merge back into Development once finished. Others in future will also do this.

I want to push "Development" into another separate folder called "Production" and for the life of me cannot figure out how to do this.

Please any suggests? How to do this?

Thanks.

I get this error when attempting.

```
Pushing to G:\03 GIS RESOURCES\05 GIS PROGRAMMING\Production
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master        
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository        
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent        
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match        
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.        
remote: error:         
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to        
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into        
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you        
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some        
remote: error: other way.        
remote: error:         
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set        
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.        
To G:\03 GIS RESOURCES\05 GIS PROGRAMMING\Production
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to 'G:\03 GIS RESOURCES\05 GIS PROGRAMMING\Production'
```

Comment: What command have you issued?

Answer (score 0):

**Option A**

You can clone your Development project into another folder.

Synopsis:

```
git clone <repository> <directory>
```

Example:

```bash
git clone <path/to/Development> Production
```

**Option B**

Copy the content of folder Development (including .git folder) to folder Production.

Comment: Get this error: Cloning into 'Production'...
done.
error: internal error: refs/remotes/origin/master is not a valid packed reference!
error: Trying to write ref refs/heads/master with nonexistent object 3f819b0c94c6afcd18a4083b7223fdc78b8ad58b
fatal: update_ref failed for ref 'HEAD': cannot update the ref 'HEAD'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: @TristanForward What folder are you in? What command have you issued?